# Codeigniter problems

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't seem to find the problem in my controller. Here's my code. I did check it using print_r($customer), all the infos were save in my table except the filename that must be save in 'file' column. I can't find the error.

```
 <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class billing extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->model('Billing_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {   

        $this->data['title'] = 'Billing';
        $this->load->view('userheader');
        $this->load->view('billing', $this->data);
        //$this->load->view('billing', array('error' => ' ' ));
        $this->load->view("userfooter");
    }

    public function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] =  './files/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpeg|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '5000';
        $config['overwrite'] = 'TRUE';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->load->initialize($config);
        $design = 'design';
        if ($this->upload->do_upload($design)) {

        $file = $this->upload->data();
        $customer = array(
            'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
            'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
            'city'      => $this->input->post('city'),
            'address'   => $this->input->post('address'),
            'email'     => $this->input->post('email'),
            'contact'   => $this->input->post('contact'),
            'status' => 'Pending',
            'file' => $file['file_name']    

        );  


        $cust_id = $this->Billing_model->insert_customer($customer);

        $order = array(
            'date'          => date('Y-m-d'),
            'customerid'    => $cust_id
        );      

        $ord_id = $this->Billing_model->insert_order($order);

        if ($cart = $this->cart->contents()):
            foreach ($cart as $item):
                $order_detail = array(
                    'orderid'       => $ord_id,
                    'productid'     => $item['id'],
                    'quantity'      => $item['qty'],
                    'price'         => $item['price']
                );      

                $cust_id = $this->Billing_model->insert_order_detail($order_detail);
            endforeach;
        endif;

        $this->load->view('userheader');
        //$this->load->view("success");
        print_r($customer);
        $this->load->view("userfooter");
    } else {
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('userheader');
            $this->load->view('errormessage', $error);
            $this->load->view('userfooter');

    }
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: What is the error? check to make sure that `$this->input->post('filename')` is actually outputting something.

Comment: i did choose a file to upload but the output is still display error message.

Comment: Will you tell us the error message or should we keep guessing?

Comment: i checked it already and i'm gguessing that the error lies in here:$this->upload->do_upload($design), but again, i can't find whats the error in that method.

Comment: `else echo $this->upload->display_errors();`

Comment: Your file upload is unsuccessful!
it keeps giving me this message

Comment: You did not select a file to upload. it shows after trying this else echo $this->upload->display_errors();

Comment: What's the name of the field for uploading the file? It needs to be "userfile" in CI. I don't think it can be anything else.

Comment: i'm using userfile already.

Comment: Check the permissions on the directory it is uploading to (and that it exists).

Comment: i already checked it, 755

Comment: Ahh... you didn't tell us the owner:group, but unless it's owned, grouped by the web server, that is your problem. Make sure a) your web server owns that directory or b) you `chmod 777 <directory name>`

Comment: yeah. Thanks. I already solved it. :)

Answer (score 1):

first of all, the class name must be like this...

```
class Billing extends CI_Controller {
```

your can save your controller as "billing.php" but the first letter of the class name always must be a capital letter.

e.g:

```
login_ctrl.php -->>> class Login_ctrl extends CI_Controller {
user_names.php -->>> class User_Names extends CI_Controller {
```

try it. perhaps now it can be run.. :)